# Is it possible to send a pull request without forking

Tags: git, github

I am curious to find a way to initiate a pull request even if the current repository is not a fork.

Let us say, a team is writing a book, for that, they created a git repository called **MyTeam/Book**. Each of the team members are responsible for contributing one chapter to this book. Whatever the reason, each of the team members **started a brand-new git repository (without forking form the MyTeam/Book)**. What we have now are **PersonA/chapter1**, **PersonB/chapter2**, **PersonX/chapterN** like that (none of this chapter has overlapping content). Is it possible for each of this chapter repositories to **initiate a pull request to the MyTeam/Book** even though they are **not a fork from MyTeam/Book**. If so how do we do that.

I couldn't find a good answer for this problem, even though there are a number of somewhat similar question exist with stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks Ron, We are looking for a solution without adding collaborators  (our requirement is slightly different than this hypothetical team working on Book and Chapter example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those team members are collaborator on the original MyTeam/Book repository, they can push their branch to that repository, assuming said branch was created from a commit existing in `MyTeam/Book`

Once the branch is pushed in the `MyTeam/Book` repository, they can initiate a PR from that branch to master, in the *same* repository.

> We are looking for a solution without adding collaborators

Then you, as owner, would need to import their branch from their repository to the original one.